# How do I get the UIPickerView to slide up over another view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, transition

I am looking for a way to slide a UIPickerView (and UIDatePickerView) up over a view (UITableView in particular) when a particular button press takes place.

I understand how to get the events for clicks into the UITableView, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to have the UIPickerView slide up on top of it...

All the examples I have seen so far just have it snapped to the bottom of another view and I am able to do this without issue.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Modally presented view controllers slide up from the bottom to cover the current view.

See the documentation for -presentModalViewController:animated: in the UIViewController Class Reference. You would invoke this method on your UITableViewController and pass the UIPickerViewController as the first parameter and YES as the second.

Answer (score 2):

An example of what Ben mentions above (Animation Blocks) is the following, which will animate to a subview.

```
UIWindow *window = [[Director sharedDirector] window];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown)
                       forView:window
                         cache:YES];
[window addSubview:aView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using UIView's animation blocks do do this? See the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView_Class.pdf) on +[UIView beginAnimations:context:] and +[UIView commitAnimations]. Basically, wrap your calls to display the UIPickerView in these calls, and you can slow it down a bit.